# Why does this provide me with undefined; jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using `parent()` and `find()` method to access the textarea of the correspoding button.

But I get undefined each time. I have tried it in a jsfiddle, but that fiddle works. Here is the code

```
<div>
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <button onclick="commentThis('10')">Post Comment</button>
  <button onclick="neverMind('10')">Never Mind</button>
</div>
```

jQuery code is as

```
function commentThis(postId) {
   var comment = $(this).parent().find("#textarea").val();
   if (comment != "" || comment != null) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "/ajax_requests/post_comment",
       data: "postId=" + postId + "&type=comment&comment=" + 
       comment + "&page=default",
       success: function (result) {
          $(".comments").append(result);
          $("#textarea").val("");
          $("#textarea").css("height", "20px");
       }
     })
   }
}
```

But it always give me a console error of undefined, saying value cannot be taken from undefine attribute.

You can see the error message here:

[image]

here is the fiddle that I created and which works. http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/ZBcby/

Comment: A string has no value property ?

Comment: Why are you passing `PostId` to the function but not using it in the function?

Comment: @Barmar, I am using that in the ajax request that is commented in the further process thing..

Comment: Note that once you get past your undefined problem your if condition `x != "" || x != null` will always be true.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find("#textarea")` doesn't make sense, because only one element on your page has the id `textarea`, all others with that id are invalid.

Comment: His fiddle does `find('textarea')`, looking for the tag rather than ID. I suspect that's what the production code does, too.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: `||` should be `&&`. It seems like everyone gets this wrong.

Comment: @KevinB, I need to find the textarea for that button, which is inside the parent element of the button. I have other posts too, which I donot want to mess the code up with, So I wanted to find the textarea inside the parent element :)

Comment: Don't give us a fiddle that works, give us a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The textarea in undefine @Barmar, when I click on the button, this error is logged in Console..

Comment: The error message should have a line number next to it. Which line of code does that line number refer to?

Comment: Nah, there is no line of error in front of it, you can see that in the console log ..

Comment: The reason your fiddle works is because you used jQuery to bind the click handler instead an inline `onclick` attribute.

Comment: The line number is on the far right, which isn't in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (comment.value != "" || comment.value != null) {
```

You got the value with `val()`. You therefore have a string. You are attempting to get the `value` property of a string. This won't work.

This will:

```
if (comment != "" || comment != null) {
```

Or, in fact, even simpler:

```
if (comment) {
```

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggested, but I am still getting the same message of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Can you update the question with your current code, please.

Comment: Have a look at the code now, I have removed that `.value` that was a mistake by me, since I was using `document.getElementById()` which was recently replaced by `$('#id')` but I forgot to update that, but the error is still there..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Does `// further process, ajax` contain `comment.value`, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry :( there was a `comment.value` in the further process too.

Comment: I tried removing that one too. But it is still an undefined error.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Debugging what is obviously quite buggy code without being able to see it is quite hard, you know...

Answer (score 1):

When you call your function like this:

```
onclick="commentThis(@row.PostId)"
```

...it doesn't set the value of `this` to the element that was clicked. `this` will be `window`. You could change it to explicitly set the value of `this`:

```
onclick="commentThis.call(this,@row.PostId)"
```

You will also need to change the following line of your function:

```
if (comment != "" || comment != null) {
```

because that if condition will *always* be true because either `comment != ""` will be true or `comment != null` will be true. You probably meant to use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if (comment != "" && comment != null) {
```

...but you can simplify that to this:

```
if (comment) {
```

(And in practice given that `comment` is the result of calling `.val()` it won't ever be `null` anyway, it will either be a string or `undefined` - and if you get the selector right it won't be `undefined`.)

Comment: Two things, one: the code still gives me the output of undefined but no console log! :( sadly, two: what does the true thing means? How will that be true always?

Comment: Sorry, I answered too quickly and messed up the `.call()` syntax. It should've been `commentThis.call(this,@row.PostId)` as per my update. I've also explained in more detail about the if condition.

Comment: Hmmm, I have tried that but was still the same error. Any guess why is still causing undefined?

Comment: I think the problem is in the code you don't show. I can't guess what it is doing.

Comment: The debugger should show you the line number and file name where the error occurred - look over to the right of the console. You can probably then click that line number to have the debugger actually show the problem code. If the error is about reading a property `value` then check all of your code for use of `.value`.